# sub total value wrong for division measure in spotfire

Tags: spotfire, tibco-topic

In the below link.
I am using cross tab for calculation.

For last column [**Measure1/Measure2**] column, the **Subtotal** value must be **467243.62** but the value is **incorrect**. But for other two columns having the desired sub total value.
I need to consider the [**Measure1/Measure2**] subtotal for further calculation.

**[Measure1]** is sum of column1

**[Measure2]** is sum of column2

**[Measure1/Measure2]** is sum(Column1)/Sum(column2)

So, Please help me to get it resolved.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your formula to:

sum([Column 1]/[Column 2])

so the division is performed before the sum.